# VBA Remove Custom Toolbar from Ribbon Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have somehow managed to create a custom tool-bar on Excel which I can't seem to get rid of either in code or via the options

I can disable the ribbon but then can see other ribbon custom tool bars

[image]

How can I loop through the menu options for the Add-Ins menu and delete what appears to be just a group here in the image??

Comment: Can you not right-click just below the word "File" and remove the toolbar?

Comment: There's no context menu for that

Comment: I mean on the AddIns tab, below where you can see the word FILE, right-click and see what options you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Add-ins Ribbon tab will appear if a workbook containing `CommandBar` customizations is opened or being loaded as an add-in. CommandBar is the VBA object representing the old menus and toolbars (pre 2007 / pre Ribbon).

This tab also appears if code has run that uses `CommandBar` objects to create old-style menus and toolbars or add controls to existing ones built into the Office application. As I recall, the "Custom Toolbars" group contains *all* non-built-in toolbars that have been defined (they don't appear in separate groups).

The following macro I have in my archives for looping all CommandBar objects in the application. If they're *not* built-in (come with the product) then the information about them is written to the VBA Editor Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and they're deleted. Built-in commandbars are reset to the installation default - changes to the default will also show up in the Add-ins tab.

```
Sub DetermineNonBuiltinCommandBars()
    Dim cb As Office.CommandBar

    For Each cb In CommandBars
        If Not cb.BuiltIn Then
            Debug.Print cb.Context & ", " & cb.Name
            cb.Delete
        Else
            cb.Reset
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I did try looping round the  CommandBars but didn't go by the BuiltIn property